# How to get information about an AppWidgetProvider widget in onUpdate

Tags: android, android-widget, android-lifecycle

During an **AppWidgetProvider onUpdate** callback, I need to know which widget instance the AppWidgetManager is referring to by the provided appWidgetId.

The widget ids seem to persist launcher (AppWidgetHost) restarts and reboots.  Do I need to maintain a persistent (as in a DB) association between the widgetId and how the widget is configured?    If I could do something like get the current RemoteView object from the widget and inspect it, or if I could associate an string, bundle or object with the widget instance, I could figure out which instance the AppWidgetManager was taking about.

Comment: What is a "widget instance"? "Do I need to maintain a persistent (id in a DB) association between the widgetId and how the widget is configured?" -- yes. "If I could do something like get the current RemoteView object from the widget and inspect it" -- I do not think that is an option, sorry.

Comment: By widget instance I meant a widget appearing on a widget host, any information associated with an 'appWidgetId' -- as opposed to an AppWidgetProvider 'class' or type of widget.   Also, not an java instance of a class.

Comment: @CommonsWare  Thanks. Related, where does AppWidgetManager persist its information about widgetId and their hosts?   I see it knows it in:   dumpsys appwidget

Comment: "where does AppWidgetManager persist its information about widgetId and their hosts?" -- I have no idea, sorry.